# ConcurrentModificationException while using temp list

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, concurrentmodification

```
public static ArrayList<Job> ready = new ArrayList<Job>();
...later on....
ArrayList<Job> temp = ready;
for (Iterator<Job> iterator = temp.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
    Job j = (Job) iterator.next();
    if (j.number == number) {
        ready.remove(j);
        ready.add(j);
        system.devices-=devices;
        j.devices+=devices;
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Why does this throw an error? Sure, ready = temp, but I'm iterating over temp and I'm not changing temp. How can I get around this problem?

Comment: You're trying to alter a list while you're iterating through it. `temp` and `ready` are the same list - changing one changes the other. If you want to *copy* the list, you could do `temp = new ArrayList<Job>(ready)`.

Comment: When posting a question about an exception, you MUST include the complete exception stack trace and identify the line in your code that throws the exception.

Comment: @khelwood You shoujld post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`temp` is a reference to `ready` any changes to `ready` will be seen by iterator of `temp`. You can actually use `Collections.copy`

```
ArrayList<Job> temp = new ArrayList<Job>();
Collections.copy( temp, ready );
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to alter a list while you're iterating through it. `temp` and `ready` are the same list - changing one changes the other. If you want to *copy* the list, you could use `temp = new ArrayList<Job>(ready)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to modify the collection while you are looping and this one Cannot support such operation. 
You have two different solutions:
1- To copy the collection to another one, and loop based on one and modify the another.
2- Best practice is to use concurrent collections such as: 
CopOnWriteArrayList, ConcurrentSkipListMap

Answer (score -2):

You are altering the list by adding and removing elements while you are iterating over it, not a good idea...

instead place those elements that meet the condition

```
if (j.number == number) {
```

in another list and the do `temp.removeAll(c);`